# Mac vim can not send R code

Tags: r, macvim

After install the `R.vim.plugin`, it works smoothly to start R by `<mapleader>rf` as well as send R code like `<mapleader>se`. HOWEVER, when I open another R file at the same time, then I can't send R code to R gui anymore. There's a message say:

```
Did you already start R?
```

The R Gui is certainly started and why it doesn't work for the second macvim file?